# How to store blockchain data in database

Tags: blockchain

I am new in blockchain. I want to know that which database should I use to store blockchain data?
How can i store blockchain data in codeigniter?

Comment: Hi there. Your question is very broad. The state data is already stored in a database. (An RLP-encoded LevelDB database.) What do you hope to achieve by storing the data in a different way? Is there a particular reason you can't just query the native data on an archive node? Do you have to have your own copy of the data? (And why?) Isn't CodeIgniter a framework? Does it mandate the use of a particular (type) of database?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot store data in CodeIgniter, as it is a MVC PHP framework to write web applications. It is no kind of data storage of any kind at all; it may just allow you to connect to one.

In case you want to write an application in CodeIgniter which will allow you to view and possibly edit blockchain data, then you would indeed either have to copy the blockchain data into a database which is supported by CodeIgniter out of the box (IIUC, LevelDB isn't one of them) or you will have to figure out how to connect CodeIgniter to LevelDB.

Given the fact that all databases which are mentioned in the CodeIgniter documentation are relational databases, your milage may vary.